# Class constructor problems

Tags: c++

I am currently writing a C++ single player, command line, blackjack game. The main problem I am having is that whenever my Player class default constructor,

```
    Player(const std::string& name = "");
```

is constructed, it seems to be defaulting even though there is input coming in from the command line to assign a name.

My Dealer class default constructor seems to work just fine because is isn't initialized to an empty string like my Player class.

```
    Dealer(const std::string& name = "Dealer");
```

It almost seems as though my code is completely forgetting the data from my input for the players' name.

I tried to narrow the code as much possible to find the problem and I have yet to find a solution. **There are no compiler errors**, but my player names just aren't showing up.

```
// ConsoleApplication2.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Player
{
public:
    Player(const std::string& name = "");
    virtual ~Player();
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& str, const Player& aPlayer);
protected:
    const std::string m_Name;
};

Player::Player(const std::string& m_name) : m_Name(m_name) {}
Player::~Player() {}

class Dealer : public Player
{
public:
    Dealer(const std::string& name = "Dealer");
    virtual ~Dealer();
};

Dealer::Dealer(const std::string& name) : Player(name) {}
Dealer::~Dealer() {}

class Game 
{
public:
    Game(const std::string& name);
    ~Game();
    void Play();
protected:
    Player newPlayer;
};

Game::Game(const std::string& name)
{
    srand(time(0));
    // I feel like something else needs to go here to initialize a player or something. Not sure what.

}
Game::~Game() {}

void Game::Play()
{
    std::cout << newPlayer << std::endl;
    // Possible this could be messing it up?
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& str, const Player& aPlayer);

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::string name;
    std::cin >> name;
    Game Game(name);
    Game.Play();
    return 0;
}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& str, const Player& aPlayer)
{
    str << aPlayer.m_Name << ":\t";

    return str;
}
```

And when I run without debugging, this is my result:

```
Enter your name: Dane
:
Dealer:
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm expecting to get a name (Dane in this case) before that first colon and it doesn't want to appear. I can't figure out the problem in my code and was wondering if anyone could give me some insight on errors in my coding.

Comment: You're going to find this question helpful, ["What is this weird colon-member (“ : ”) syntax in the constructor?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor). I can almost guarantee it.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Game` constructor you should initialize the `Player` object `newPlayer`, passing on the argument to it (how else would the `newPlayer` object be initialized with the name?).

You do this with a constructor *member initializer list*:

```
Game::Game(const std::string& name)
    : newPlayer(name)  // This is the member initializer list
{
    ...
}
```

See e.g. [this constructors and member initializer lists reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) for more information.

Comment: It's crazy how easy it is to see when it's put into normal words rather than textbook words. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to pass name to your player:

```
Game::Game(const std::string& name) :
    newPlayer(name)
{
    srand(time(0));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define Your Game class as follows, and do not for get to clear the `pointer` to Player in your destructor

```
class Game 
{
public:
    Game(const std::string& name);
    ~Game();
    void Play();
protected:
    Player *newPlayer;
};

Game::Game(const std::string& name)
{
    srand(time(0));
    // I feel like something else needs to go here to initialize a player or something. Not sure what.
    this->newPlayer = new Player( name );
}


void Game::Play()
{
    std::cout << (*newPlayer) << std::endl;
    // Possible this could be messing it up?
}
```